# Console log outputs one too many times on function

Tags: javascript

I have a function and at the bottom I'm doing `console.log`.

Now I want to run this function twice and in order to keep things simple I figured I'd just copy/paste the entire function below the first one.

The problem is that the console now outputs three times; the first, the second, and then the first again. Why does this happen? And what should I do to output only twice?

```
(function test (dx, dy, w, h) {
    // arguments:
    // pixels region to read, from canvas upper right corner
    // note that height (h) counts upwards

    // they store context in global GLctx var, but it seem to expire often, so grab the current one
    var GLctx = document.getElementById ('glcanvas').getContext ('webgl');

    // we need to wait until after they are done drawing stuff, so we intercept requestAnimationFrame
    var rAF = window.requestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function () {
        rAF.apply (window, arguments); window.requestAnimationFrame = rAF;

        var pixels = new Uint8Array (w * h * 4);
        GLctx.readPixels (GLctx.canvas.width - dx, GLctx.canvas.height - dy, w, h, GLctx.RGBA, GLctx.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

        if (pixels[3] == 0) {
            // blank image - retry
            return test (dx, dy, w, h);
        }

        // debug: log the pixels
        //console.log (pixels);

        // debug: see the pixels
        var canvas = document.createElement ('canvas'); canvas.width = w; canvas.height = h;
        var imageData = canvas.getContext ('2d').getImageData (0, 0, w, h);
        for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) for (var p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
            // actual pixels data comes upside-down
            imageData.data[4 * (w * (h - y - 1) + x) + p] = pixels[4 * (w * y + x) + p];
        }
        canvas.getContext ('2d').putImageData (imageData, 0, 0);
        //console.log (canvas.toDataURL ());

        // from the screenshot, their green color RGB values seem to be 43 171 63
        // so we can test for the pixel to be green by something like g > 170
        var count = 0;
        var count2 = 0;
        for (var p = 0; p < pixels.length; p += 4) {
            //rgb(58, 66, 85)
            var red = pixels[p], green = pixels[p + 1], blue = pixels[p + 2];

             if (green > 170) count++; 
             if (green > 120) count2++;             

        }


        if(count == 48){ count = 1};
        if(count == 61){ count = 7};
        if(count == 78){ count = 3};

        if(count == 83){ 

          if(count2 == 105){ count = 2}; 
          if(count2 == 115){ count = 9}; 

        }

        if(count == 85){ count = 6};

        if(count == 87){

         if(count2 == 109){ count = 4}; 
         if(count2 == 105){ count = 5};

        }

        if(count == 90){ count = 0};
        if(count == 100){ count = 8};


        console.log(count);


    };
}) (59, 393, 15, 29);
```

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Dont get it....Code is not that large

Comment: Where's your HTML? If you can provide a testable example, you'll probably get better answers. Also, it looks like the amount of times your `test()` function is called is dependent on whether or not a blank image occurs, which results in `return test (dx, dy, w, h);`.

Comment: HTML is just one canvas called by document.getElementById ('glcanvas')

Comment: nothing special...

Comment: The solution is clearly not to copy-paste code N times all around your files. You should take a second look at what your code does. `console.log` wherever it's possible and creating breakpoints `debugger;` would help. Even if your variables are in scope don't forget you're using `window`

Comment: I would think most variables are locked in the scope

Comment: @freginold  I see what you mean, thanks, maybe thats the problem

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan  window of course thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've provided, it looks like the problem stems from your `if` statement that checks for a blank image:

```
if (pixels[3] == 0) {
    // blank image - retry
    return test (dx, dy, w, h);
}
```

If the condition is met, `test()` will get called, so if a blank image is produced multiple times, you could end up with the function being called more than you anticipated.

To see if this is where the problem lies, insert a `console.log` statement so you can see how often this condition evaluates to true, thus calling `test()`.

Something like this would work:

```
if (pixels[3] == 0) {
    // blank image - retry
    console.log('blank image... calling test()');
    return test (dx, dy, w, h);
}
```

Then you could see how often `test()` is being called as a result of that `if` check.